# React Native app on iPhone X Uses Significant CPU and crashes

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native, iphone-x

I have a React Native app that runs great on most iPhone models, but lately have received complaints from users on iPhone X that the app often freezes and crashes. I tried it out in the simulator on Mac, and the simulator immediately uses 100% of my computer CPU and the app quickly freezes. This does not happen with the other models.

I have no custom code for the iPhone X. Is there any general change made on the X that would cause some code that was fine before to become extremely inefficient, or for some React component to rerender much more than before?